# Print name where array exists

Tags: javascript

I have this block of code:

```
var data = {
        sand: [['sun', 'moon', 'cool'], ['man', 'store', 'rose', 'big', 'you', 'sharp', 'low', 'high'], ['hot', 'cool', 'lip'], ['store', 'man', 'lip']],
        king: [['store', 'man', 'lip'], ['store', 'man', 'lip'], ['store', 'man', 'lip']],
        house: [['lip', 'store', 'hot', 'bed', 'you', 'low', 'run', 'high'], ['cool', 'sun', 'hot', 'big', 'sharp', 'low', 'run', 'high'], ['high', 'cool', 'moon', 'lip', 'man'], ['man', 'store', 'rose', 'big', 'you', 'sharp', 'low', 'high']],
        bow: [['lip', 'store', 'hot', 'bed', 'you', 'low', 'run', 'high'], ['bed', 'moon', 'lip'], ['low', 'cool', 'lip', 'man']],
        queen: [['cool', 'awe'], ['low', 'dad'], ['usa', 'cool', 'ita'], ['bed', 'glass', 'store', 'sal']],
}
```

I want to print all names where `['store', 'man', 'lip']` exists. So, what should be printed is: sand, king. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a set for each array to compare with and filter the keys of the object by checking the values with the values of the sets at the same index.

```js
function getKeys(object, pattern) {
    return Object
        .keys(data)
        .filter(key => data[key].some(a =>
            a.length === pattern.length &&
            pattern.every((p, i) => a[i] === p)
        ));
}

var data = {
        sand: [['sun', 'moon', 'cool'], ['man', 'store', 'rose', 'big', 'you', 'sharp', 'low', 'high'], ['hot', 'cool', 'lip'], ['store', 'man', 'lip']],
        king: [['store', 'man', 'lip'], ['store', 'man', 'lip'], ['store', 'man', 'lip']],
        house: [['lip', 'store', 'hot', 'bed', 'you', 'low', 'run', 'high'], ['cool', 'sun', 'hot', 'big', 'sharp', 'low', 'run', 'high'], ['high', 'cool', 'moon', 'lip', 'man'], ['man', 'store', 'rose', 'big', 'you', 'sharp', 'low', 'high']],
        bow: [['lip', 'store', 'hot', 'bed', 'you', 'low', 'run', 'high'], ['bed', 'moon', 'lip'], ['low', 'cool', 'lip', 'man']],
        queen: [['cool', 'awe'], ['low', 'dad'], ['usa', 'cool', 'ita'], ['bed', 'glass', 'store', 'sal']],
    },
    pattern = ['store', 'man', 'lip'];

console.log(getKeys(data, pattern));
```